# How to grep for particular substring containing "-" dash symbols

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I am trying to run

```
clear && docker logs 0d5f6a87fc49 | grep "9c3bc6e0\-af6e\-11ed\-9412\-edc770e32f93"
```

As for me it looks pretty straightforward: "find strings containing a substring"

But no matter what I am do, grep finds any string containing any bit of uuid `["9c3bc6e0", "af6e", "11ed", "9412", "edc770e32f93"]`

I have tried to escape dashes, build three types of regexps an no luck

Regex builders works fine with my "query", so they do not provide any answers

Test data

```
uid:[9c3bc6e0-af6e-11ed-9412-edc770e32f93]
uid:[0ca73150-b28d-11ed-a5db-27071701f8e4]
uid:[d95c75e0-b295-11ed-a5db-27071701f8e4]
uid:[621ec330-b2a3-11ed-a5db-27071701f8e4]
uid:[6a6ee7e0-b2a3-11ed-a5db-27071701f8e4]
uid:[525714a0-b2a5-11ed-a5db-27071701f8e4]
uid:[93807250-b2a5-11ed-a5db-27071701f8e4]
uid:[93875020-b2a5-11ed-a5db-27071701f8e4]
uid:[93881370-b2a5-11ed-a5db-27071701f8e4]
uid:[93886190-b2a5-11ed-a5db-27071701f8e4]
```

Edit: starnge behavior, when i am saving data to file grep works fine(`cat greptest.log  | grep "9c3bc6e0\-af6e\-11ed\-9412\-edc770e32f93"`), when using it from docker it just lists everything

Comment: Are you sure your `grep` isn't an alias?

Comment: Why are you escaping the dashes? You shouldn't have to.

Comment: grep (GNU grep) 3.4

Comment: escaping or not does not help, ihave tried numerous combinations

Comment: Can't reproduce. As a test, `(echo 9c3bc6e0; echo 9c3bc6e0-af6e-11ed-9412-edc770e32f93) | grep "9c3bc6e0-af6e-11ed-9412-edc770e32f93"` works exactly as expected.

Comment: please update the question with the output from `docker logs 0d5f6a87fc49`; if the output is more than 10-15 lines then reduce it to 10-15 lines, making sure to include at least one line you with to match on, at least one line that should not match, and a couple lines that match but should not

Comment: added some test data, tried on it with mode confusing results

Comment: Could it be that `docker logs` is outputting to stderr?

Comment: shoud check this

Comment: fwiw re: output to stderr ... run `docker logs 0d5f6a87fc49 >std.out 2>std.err` and see what's in each file (`std.out`, `std.err`)